# Connection string for SQL Server Express 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

On Win 7 system I installed SQL Server 2014 Express. I created instance `HM1`. I've set it up to use mixed mode. I created a SQL Server user and I am able to login with no issue.

My goal is to connect to a database using this SQL Server user using configuration file. This connection will be used for another application. Note: if I disable user/password usage during login I have no problem but I have to use credentials.

For connection I provided `machine_name\SQLSERVEREXPRESS\HM1`. I also provided username and password. I also changed the service for `SQLEXPRESS` and `HM1` to run as local account.

When I try to connect using that file I've got the error

> Can't connect to database

Again if I disable user/password usage I am able to connect using the same file with no problem.

Could someone help me with it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify: do you want to use SQL Server security or windows trusted security?

Comment: I have to use SQL Server security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For connection I provided "machine_name\SQLSERVEREXPRESS\HM1".

You just want this:

> machine_name\HM1

That's probably not your only problem, but that's all I can tell you until you try that and then come back and include more detail from the error message.

Comment: Well .. I used format machine_name\HM1. I've got the same error: "Can't connect to database". I checked log file and it stated this: Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8. Login failed for user 'tester'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided [CLIENT: <local machin>. Note. I am using SQL authentication, username is 'tester'. I used Base64 encoding to create a password and used it when created login for 'tester'. I could login using those credentials. I have to use Base64 encoding because application expects it. What should be my next step? Thanks

Comment: Something isn't right with how you encode the password. You'll need to troubleshoot what you enter with what your application is producing.

Comment: Well ... the issue is narrowed down i.e. it's around credentials. If I disable credential check ( which I can't) it works, if I enable it throws error about password. Well I am confused about that issue: I created a new user e.g. user1 with the password that I encoded using Base64. Now I can login using 'user1' and that password. I put this data inside configuration file but it throws the error about password. What I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the un-encoded password in the config file instead of the base64 encoded one. Alternatively, you can also put `Trusted_Connection=True;` in the connection string if your database server resides on the same server as the application server. This will use the OS credentials instead of the username/password that you provide.